# Hyper-V core management options

Tags: hyper-v, hypervisor

I have installed Hyper-V standalone on a server and configured server options using sconfig.cmd. I am now stuck as to how I create VMs, back them up etc.

Our environment has only XP pro workstations, 2003 servers & a 2008 server across a VPN. I was hoping I could use RSAT on the 2008 standard box to get at the Hyper-V management console but there are no options in the server admin and I can only locate install files from Microsoft for use with RSAT Vista SP1 [http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9ff6e897-23ce-4a36-b7fc-d52065de9960&displaylang=en].

Can anyone she any light where I can go next with this, I have also tried CoreConfig & Hyper-V Management Console but neither allows for creation of VMs. Guess my otpions are:

1 - Buy Windows 7 Ultimate or Vista to use RSAT

2 - Buy Windows server 2008 enterprise to use RSAT

3 - Find a version of RSAT that works on Windows 2008 Standard

Any advice appreciated, haven't really got the money for any more upgrades.

Thanks

Comment: Why 3?  To my knowledge RSAT works on all 2008 and all Win7.

Comment: That's what I was hoping but my 2008 standard install doesn't seem to have any tools and I can only locate the Vista SP1 or Win7 downloads from MS?

Comment: That is because you did not install them. Install the admin tools manually (i.e. through server manager) and all management tools are there for install. In general, unless you install manually, only the tools for installed components are there.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way to manage it would be to use RDP to the stand alone server and use the tools there. But that can be a big pain. I would suggest that you upgrade your work station to Win 7 pro. You do not need ultimate to run RSAT, just Pro is fine. OF course there is also SCOM as well, but that's just too much $$$ for a single Hyper-V Server.

Comment: Hi Robert,
I can RDP into the server but as I am sure you know there are only tools to configure the server from what I can see, nothing to actually manage or create guest VMs?

I've been on this all day so maybe getting confused but are there definitely not tools on a standard 2008 installation, this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950050 appears to offer the management tools for a 32bit 2008 Standard install which I do have albeit on the other end of a VPN in a data centre?

Thanks again.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950050

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950050

Comment: If he wants to manage a core Hyper-V machine, using RDP isn't going to help any more than sitting at the console.

Comment: You are correct. For some reason it did not register in my mind this was a server core install.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a core Hyper-V install, your only options are RSAT from a Win7 or 2008 machine. It's not meant to do what you want (which sounds like you want to create VMs from the core machine?) by design. If you want to manage it from that machine, you need an actual server OS with the Hyper-V role installed.

Comment: Hi Dan,
No I do want to manage this remotely just haven't got Win 7 Pro or Vista as desktops, still stuck on XP at present due to constraints in budgets! I do have a Windows server 2008 32 bit machine but that doesnt currently contain any software for managemnet console. As post below do you think this is what I'm after http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=6F69D661-5B91-4E5E-A6C0-210E629E1C42&displaylang=en

Comment: Open Server Manager on the 2008 box, and at the top of the menu tree, right click and Connect to Another Computer. Put in the name of your Hyper-V box and it will show you the roles installed, and allow you to manage. This is assuming these are all domain connected machines, and you can authenticate from one to the other.

Comment: Hi Dan, yes I tried that earlier but option to connect to other computer isn't available, I guess maybe because the 2008 box is in its own workgroup?

Comment: I'm not sure why that option isn't available. But I will tell you this, when I first started using Hyper-V and ran into the same problem of not being able to administer it, I quickly realized it was time to move to Win7.

Comment: Hah Dan I think you may be right, perhaps I need to look at that option rather than messing with a production 2008 server! Is the console good to manage all aspects of the VMs?

Comment: Which console are you talking about?

Comment: I take it you use Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate Dan?

Comment: I use Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to like this answer, but the equivalent VMware free bare-metal hypervisor (ESXi) and management client (vSphere Client, also free) would work in your scenario.  The vSphere Client runs on XP and offers full management capabilities including VM creation.

Comment: Yes I may need to go down that route if all else fails, had a play before deciding on Hyper-V, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

on the windows 2008 server just goto add features rsat is a feature!

so it looks better

### **on client

netsh firewall add allowedprogram program=%windir%\system32\mmc.exe name="Microsoft Management Console"

net localgroup "Distributed COM Users" /add hyper-v-1\gary

### on server

net localgroup "Distributed COM Users" /add hyper-v-1\gary

**
found this on the net

Comment: Good point Tony, that did install RSAT many thanks. The 2 servers are both in seperate workgroups so will have to work out how to connect now!

Comment: do you want the answer for that also?

Comment: They can however speak to each other though, cant ping but I can RDP from server 2008 onto the Hyper-V box. When connecting fro the Hyper-V manager I get "check that the virtual machine management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server". This service is running so I am thing it must be Firewall related in some way?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2008/11/14/configure-hyper-v-remote-management-in-seconds.aspx

this will help

Comment: Hi Tony,
During setup of Hyper-V core I added a user account with identical settings to the server which is hosting the manager console. I am logged into both machines with that password, and it now connects but prompts me with DCOM errors, just working my way through that script now so heres hoping, thanks for your help.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Much thanks to you all, I got Anytime Upgrade via MS which has resolved all issues.

Regards